# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'ï»¿44\n'

Tags: python-3.x

Hi I am struggling with this assignment for the week, I am a beginner coder in python 3 and the assignement is to takes numbers from a file as batting averages then find the averages. The problem is whenever I get to the point to read the file the parts of the files are str I understand that and want to change them to ints however it is not working and I was wondering if there is a fix or a way to get around it.

```
def main(filename = 'bats.txt'):
hits = 0
bats = 0
app = 0
bases = 0
for line in open(filename, 'r'):
    contents = int(line.strip()) #does the placement of int here not work? 
    if contents > 4:
        playerNum = contents
        print(playerNum)
    elif contents <= 4 and contents >= 1:
        hits += 1
    elif contents <= 4 and contents >= 0:
        bats += 1
        print(bats)
    elif contents <= 4 and contents >= -1:
        app += 1        
    else:
        bases += 1
```

The assignment is a work in process and I am completely stumped by this part as it does not let me continue. Thank you to whoever can help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

Before converting validate whether the string can be converted to int. You can use regular expressions for doing that.

Always catch exception (Since we are not sure of the value that is coming from the file) this will ensure the program executes and provides are nice user experience

```
try:
    int(line)
except ValueError:
    print "Not a float"
```